Can we authenticate to ETCD with TLS cert AND password for the same connection?
I want to configure my ETCD cluster to enable authentication with TLS certificate and password at the same time (for the same connection, not just enable the two authentication mechanisms).
Then for a client to authenticate, it must :

provide a valid certificate with the username set in the common name and signed by a trusted root ca
provide a password for this specific user

I want to do this to improve safety. This way, even if my client certificate or my root CA are leaked, you still need a password to authenticate.
I manage to enable password authentication without TLS but if I turn on TLS client authentication (with --client-cert-auth=true at the start of the cluster), it does not ask for a password anymore (even thought the user has one).
I started my 3 nodes cluster with the following command (accordingly changing the env vars for each node) :
etcd --name ${THIS_NAME} --data-dir data/etcd/${TOKEN} \
    --initial-cluster ${CLUSTER} --initial-cluster-state ${CLUSTER_STATE} --initial-cluster-token ${TOKEN} \
    --initial-advertise-peer-urls https://${THIS_IP}:2380 --listen-peer-urls https://${THIS_IP}:2380 \
    --peer-client-cert-auth --peer-trusted-ca-file=ca.pem \
    --peer-cert-file=member.pem --peer-key-file=member-key.pem \
    --advertise-client-urls https://${THIS_IP}:2379 --listen-client-urls https://${THIS_IP}:2379 \
    --client-cert-auth --trusted-ca-file=ca.pem \
    --cert-file=server.pem --key-file=server-key.pem

And I turned on authentication like that :
etcdctl --endpoints=$ENDPOINTS --cacert=ca.pem --cert=root.pem --key=root-key.pem user add root --new-user-password=root
etcdctl --endpoints=$ENDPOINTS --cacert=ca.pem --cert=root.pem --key=root-key.pem role add root
etcdctl --endpoints=$ENDPOINTS --cacert=ca.pem --cert=root.pem --key=root-key.pem user grant-role root root
etcdctl --endpoints=$ENDPOINTS --cacert=ca.pem --cert=root.pem --key=root-key.pem auth enable

Note that before I enable auth, I still need to provide a valid client certificate, it just does not check the CN of the client to authenticate to an existing user, whereas after it does.
I can't find out how to do that in documentation. Then is it even possible to do this and if yes, how ?

As of now, etcd does not natively support combining TLS certificate-based authentication with password-based authentication for a single connection. It only supports one method at a time for client authentication, either certificate-based or, not and,  password-based.
